# SchemeString, precedence of uppercase and match

Tags: mongoose

I would like to add a `gender` field which accepts `[MmFf]` and normalizes to `[MF]`.
Here's my schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    gender : { type: String, upper: true, match: /[MmFf]/ }
});
```

I wonder what's the sequence of execution of the SchemeString functions.
If `uppercase` is executed before `match`, my `match` could as well be `[MF]`.

I also have similar question concerning `trim` and `match`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by Aaron Heckmann
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongoose-orm/L5ztQDFbBWU/gYoStZv1eHIJ

> upper and trim are setters - when the value is assigned it is
>   modified.
>
> match is a validator - executed later when calling .validate() or
>   .save()